# Firebase deploy after test to production environment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have created 2 separate projects in Firebase one for the TEST (development) and one for the actual PROD(unction) environment.

I have create a hosting project and am also using Firebase functions that I have successfully deployed and tested on the Firebase TEST project (using the command line as described in the docs).

What is the best / easiest way to now publish to the Firebase PROD project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get familiar with the way the Firebase CLI lets you attach a workspace to multiple projects.  You can use `firebase use --add` on the command line to add a project alias, then `firebase use [project]` to switch between projects for deployment.

[You can find the documentation for managing aliases here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#managing_project_aliases)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have a custom initializeapp call in my nodejs. The databaseurl, credential... are environment specific. What is the best practice to automatically switch those depending on prod and test?

Comment: If you have a followup question that's different than the first, please ask an entirely new question here on SO.  But I will note that the question your asking depends highly on opinion, which is not appropriate for this site.